# possible to ignore a KeyError?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I have a simple bit of code that goes into aws and grabs some data then prints it out to console

MyCode:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

#This is the VPC ID and Linked Tags
for vpctags in client.describe_vpcs()['Vpcs']: 
    print("VPC ID: ", vpctags['VpcId']) 
    print("Tags: ", vpctags['Tags'])
    for subnet in client.describe_subnets()['Subnets']:
        print("Subnet ID: ", subnet['SubnetId'])
        print("Subnet ID: ", subnet['Tags'])

###############################################
```

I get an error because one or more of my subnets don't have tags:

> print("Subnet ID: ", subnet['Tags']) KeyError: 'Tags'

I'm not expecting every subnet to have tags so is there a way to simply ignore the lack of tags and just print empty or simply move on?

sorry if this sounds like a silly question, I've searched google and found some ideas but they look a little advanced for what I have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes,
You can replace

```
print("Subnet ID: ", subnet['Tags'])
```

with

```
print("Subnet ID: ", subnet.get('Tags', ''))
```

Using get with allow you to define a default value in case Tags doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

Catch the [`KeyError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError):

```
try:
    print("Tags: ", vpctags['Tags'])
except KeyError:
    print("Tags: None")
```

---

If the `Tags` key doesn't exist, it will instead print "None".

Answer (score 3):

much better than trapping the exception: use `get`

```
print("Tags: ", vpctags.get('Tags',"None"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
if 'Tags' in subnet:
  print("Subnet ID: ", subnet['Tags'])
```

Comment: While this would make the KeyError go away, it also will not run the `print(...` statement to show that the value is missing. I don't think that's what OP was after, but it's exactly what I was looking for when I found this in a Google search.